# MEAN app in production: cannot call backend API

Tags: node.js, angular, routes, mean-stack

I am trying to deploy my MEAN app. Before doing that on heroku or some other place, I am testing the production mode. Everything works in "development mode" when I launch Node and Angular separately on two different ports. In production mode i cannot reach the backend API.

Using environment variables (see below) I have Node.js/Express server the Angular compiled code in /dist. These are some relevant excerpts from the Node.js code:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require('path')
const cors = require('cors');
const  mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();
... //some non-relevant stuff eg passport, body-parser ...

//Load configurations
const config = require('./config/config.js');
// Load routes
const storeroutes = require('./routes/stores.routes.js');
//Use mongoose to connect to the stores DB in mongoDB

mongoose.connect(config.mongoDB, { useNewUrlParser: true });
mongoose.connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log('Connection to the MongoDB database established successfully!');
});
// CORS Middleware
app.use(cors());
...
// Static Folders (used by Node)
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Serve Angular
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production') {
  app.use(express.static("../dist/"));
  app.use((req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/index.html')); 
  });
}

// Use routes
app.use('/', storeroutes)

app.listen(config.port);
```

The config/config.js just exports the environment variables.. so trust me that NODE_ENV='production', config.port=4000, and others that I don't show.

The routes in stores.routes.js is basically an express router and, as I said, everything works in development mode. For example, in development mode the API at `http://localhost:4000/stores` shows on the mongoDB database

When I launch `NODE_ENV=production node server.js` the front-end page shows correctly, but under the hood the calls to the server API fail, see the screenshots. In fact I cannot navigate to the API link above.

In my Angular service I call the API as follows:

```
export class StoreService {
  uri:string = environment.node_url; //this is 'http://localhost:4000'
  // Fetches all documents.
  getAllStores() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.uri}/stores`);
  }
  ...
}
```

I suspect the problem is in the Node/Express code `app.use((req, res) => { res.sendFile(..`, but maybe if it is a problem in the url to the API that I use in Angular (should I try using `baseUrl` somehow?).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below forces all routing to the front-end's index.html:

```
app.use((req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/index.html')); 
});
```

I first made it work by removing those lines. 
However, a better solution was to place the backend API **above** as follows:

```
// Use routes for backend API
app.use('/', storeroutes)

// Serve Angular
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production') {
  app.use(express.static("../dist/"));
  // Any request that is not the storeroutes above goes to Angular client
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist','index.html')); 
  });
}
```